# How to check if a "not allowed" word or symbol is contained in text?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, validation

Let's say I have a list with allowed symbols and words like follows:

```
+ - TEXT \s
```

and a `valid`  string is a string which does not contain other symbols or words.

For example, the following are `valid` strings:

```
TEXT + TEXT
TEXT - TEXT
```

and the following are not:

```
NUMBER + TEXT
TEXT / TEXT
```

I need some help for building a regular expression which can be used for applying such validation. My issue is that I am not able to combine the symbols with the words in the regular expression.

For example, the above is working fine, when symbols are validated:

```
(?n)[^\s\+-] # it is matching everything that is not a "space", "+" or "-"
```

but if I try to add a word, the expression matches its characters, not the word itself:

```
(?n)[^\s\+-\bTEXT\b]
```

I have try different regular expressions (separating the arguments with `|`, `()`) but failed.

Could anyone tell who to solve this?

Comment: Why using a regex? Create a list of strings and then use it with LINQ `All`/`Any` method. Or do you want to say that you actually have a list of allowed *patterns* ? Does `\s` means *any whitespace*?

Comment: Something like this? _https://regex101.com/r/pC7pI8/1_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggest is using a `"(?:" + string.Join("|", list) + ")"` to create a regex pattern for checking incoming strings:

A sample regex would look like:

```
 ^(?:\+|-|TEXT|\s)+$
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F%3A%5C%2B%7C-%7CTEXT%7C%5Cs)%2B%24&i=For%20example%2C%20the%20following%20are%20valid%20strings%3A%0D%0A%0D%0ATEXT%20%2B%20TEXT%0D%0ATEXT%20-%20TEXT%0D%0Aand%20the%20following%20are%20not%3A%0D%0A%0D%0ANUMBER%20%2B%20TEXT%0D%0ATEXT%20%2F%20TEXT&o=m)

And C# code:

```
var keys = new List<string>() { @"\+", "-", "TEXT", @"\s" };
var pattern = string.Format("(?:{0})", string.Join("|", keys));
Regex rx = null;
try
{
    rx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
    var text = "TEXT+TEXT";
    if (rx.IsMatch(text))
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("\"{0}\" is valid.", text));
    else
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("\"{0}\" is invalid.", text));
}
catch (ArgumentException ae)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Error parsing {0}: {1}", pattern, ae.Message));
}
```

Note you must make sure the keys are valid regex subpatterns. If not, you need to use `Regex.Escape` to escape special regex metacharacters.

Answer (score 2):

You can rely on `Replace`. Sample code:

```
string input = "TEXT+TEXT";
List<string> allAllowed = new List<string>() { "+", "-", "TEXT", @"\s" };

//In case of having allowed words sharing common parts (e.g., TEXT & SUBTEXT), 
//you would have to order the list by word-length to avoid problems
//allAllowed = allAllowed.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).ToList();

string outString = input;
foreach (string allowed in allAllowed)
{
    outString = outString.Replace(allowed, "").Trim();

    //As suggested by Erresen via comments I am including Trim() 
    //because in the provided samples the blank spaces are not invalid characters.
}

bool inputIsValid = (outString == "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^TEXT(?:[\s+-]+TEXT)*$
```

Use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/14

Comment: It works but why we use `\bTEXT\b` at the beginning? Also, I guess we can remove the `^ beg` and `$ end`? Could you explain a little bit.

Comment: @gotqn `\b` is not needed.Also `^$` are necessary to avoid `partial` matches.